# Double integral with subsitution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to prove that $\int_1^\infty \int_1^\infty \frac{y_1^{-2} y_2^{-1}}{\sqrt{2\pi\Gamma_{12}}}\exp(-\frac{(\log(\frac{y_2}{y_1})+\frac{\Gamma_{12}}{2})^2}{2\Gamma_{12}}) dy_1 dy_2 = 2\Phi(\frac{\sqrt{\Gamma_{12}}}{2})$, where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution and $\Gamma_{12} > 0$.

I have tried one-dimensional substitution with $u = \log(\frac{y_2}{y_1})+\frac{\Gamma_{12}}{2}$ and $du = y_2^{-1} dy_2$, and tried different substitution such as $u =  \log(\frac{y_2}{y_1})+\frac{\Gamma_{12}}{2}$ and $v = y_2^{-1} but none has worked so far.

How would one go about proving this?
[image]

*Engelke, Sebastian; Hitz, Adrien S.*, [**Graphical models for extremes**](https://doi.org/10.1111/rssb.12355),  [ZBL07554779](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07554779).